# Using Steam to lift a mass?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a task set to create a system to produce the largest values for potential energy, mgh.

I am given 1 litre of boiling water and with this use the steam produced to lift the mass of weight that i can select. I am not aloud to add any energy to the system. I am not aloud to use pre-made equipment such as thermo-generators. £30 is the limit.

I have had some ideas that have been thrown down the drain as the were deemed not satisfactory.
First, i suggested  using a steam gun by collecting the steam then releasing it all at once.
Then, i suggested making a Thermo-electric system to a motor, but again it said it was deemed to not have enough torque.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how many times this device must be used ?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum potential energy is limited by the energy content released by the one liter of boiling water.  you are able to boil away all of the water - this gives you the total energy released.

The obvious answer is to follow Watt and build a steam engine - the height of the piston is the measure of the potential energy extracted, U=mgh.  You can use a ratchet to prevent the piston from falling down.